# Agregar un contacto si no existe

Tags: java

Tengo los siguientes metodos y necesito agregar contactos si no existe en la lista

```
public boolean agregarContacto(Contacto contacto){
        Contacto temp = buscarPorCedula(contacto.getCedula());
        if () {
            contactos.add(contacto);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public Contacto buscarPorCedula(String cedulaContacto){
        Contacto temp = null;
        for (int i=0 ; i < contactos.size();i++){
            temp = contactos.get(i);
            if (temp.getCedula().equals(cedulaContacto)) {
                return temp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Pero no se como trabajar con la variable `temp` ya que si la pongo en el `if` me dice que no puedo ya que no es un valor booleano

Comment: `temp` por si sola lógicamente no devuelve un valor booleano ya que no es de este tipo. La condición de un `if` siempre tiene que poder ser evaluada como verdadero o falso. En este caso tu método `buscarPorCedula` te devuelve o bien un Contacto o bien `null`. Para que se ejecute el código dentro del `if` cuando no encuentre un contacto tendras que ponerle como condicion `if(temp==null)`

Comment: Gracias!! me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Estas excelente con el código pero puedes simplificar un poco más.

```
 //He modificado y simplificado este código
 public boolean buscarPorCedula(String cedulaContacto){         
        for (int i=0 ; i < contactos.size();i++){
            if (contactos.get(i).getCedula().equals(cedulaContacto)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



public boolean agregarContacto(Contacto contacto){

        if (buscarPorCedula(contacto.getCedula())) {
            contactos.add(contacto);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```